# A question about Cayley-Hamilton's density proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

The usual Cayley-Hamilton proof using density is something like this:

> Lemma: Let $f,g:X\to Y$ be two continuous functions in metric spaces $X$ and $Y$. If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in E$, where $E$ is a dense subset of $X$, then $f=g$.
>
> Let $\chi_A$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Since it is trivial to prove Cayley-Hamilton for diagonalizable matrices and the set of all diagonalizable matrices is dense in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ we can argue as follows.
>   If $A$ is any matrix, there is a sequence of diagonalizable matrices $A_k$ such that $A_k\to A$. Hence, $\chi_{A_k}(A_k)\to\chi_A(A)$ by our lemma. Since $\chi_{A_k}(A_k)=O_n$ (because CH holds for diagonalizable matrices), it follows that $\chi_A(A)=O_n$.

My problem with this proof is the following step: "Hence, $\chi_{A_k}(A_k)\to\chi_A(A)$ by our lemma."

I do not find this obvious. Why is the function $f(A)=\chi_A(A)$ continuous? It is clear that, for a fixed matrix $B$, the function $g(A)=\chi_B(A)$ is continuous as it is a polynomial. However that does not seem to be enough.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Thanks.

EDIT: I further explained my trouble.

> Consider the functions $f(A)=\chi_A$ and $g(p)=p(A)$. $f$ maps $A$ to its characteristic polynomial and $g$ gets some polynomial and applies $A$ to it.
>   Clearly the map $A\mapsto \chi_A(A)$ is the function $g\circ f$.
>
> $f$ is continuous since $f(A)=\det(xI-A)$. That is, $f$ is polynomial in the entries of $A$.

However, why does $g$ is continuous? How can I prove it?

Comment: The only thing you want to check is that the function $\chi$ mapping a square matrix to its characteristic polynomial is continuous from the space of square matrices (with standard affine topology) to the space of polynomials (endowed with the subspace topology induced from the space of continuous functions). Can you go on from here?

Comment: @cjackal, actually not. I thought about that. If I could prove that the result would follow immediately since the composition of continuous functions is continuous. But I couldn't figure out why $\chi$ is continuous. I'm not very good in topology yet.

Comment: Each entry of $\chi_A(A)$ is a polynomial in the components of $A$.

Comment: @orangeskid, my intuition also says so but I can't formalize this. Could you explain it further?

Comment: Take a particular case $n=2$. THe characteristic pol has some coefficients, you need to raise $A$ to some powers, then you sum all up, surely the entries at each step are poly, so is the sum.

Comment: @orangeskid check my edit please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\chi_A^i$ be the coefficient of $x^i$ in $\chi_A$. I believe you agree that each $\chi_A^i$ is a continuous function of $A$.

Then

$$\chi_A(A) = \sum_{i=0}^n \chi_A^i A^i$$
is the sum of products of continuous functions and thus continuous.